# Ответ при нажатие на URL кнопку в Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, url

[image]

При программирование бота для Telegram у меня возникла проблема с командой `/help`. Мне нужно расширенно описать функционал бота и сделать ответы на заданные вопросы. Хотел сделать, чтобы человек нажимал на вопрос и бот отправлял ему пояснение, но с помощью Markdown такое можно сделать только с ссылкой. Не хочу направлять все на сайт, так как это не удобно.

Comment: В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Ммм... Объяснить так и не смог. Я находил музыкального бота в Telegram, и там тебе выбивается список песен. Ты нажимаешь на название любой песни и тебе отправляется сама песня. Но список этот выглядел как набор URL ссылок, при этом тебя не перенаправляет ни на какой сайт. Объяснить очень сложно, так как такое я встретил в первый раз.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating

Comment: Да, идея с использованием сallback-кнопки хороша, но тут уже вопрос в эстетическом плане. Использовать больше 2-х кнопок будет резать глас пользователю. Можно еще попробовать использовать команды (через "/"), но тут тоже есть много минусов. Если мне не изменяет память, то кириллица со "/" работать не будет. А для русскоязычных пользователей это большой минус. Я пока не нашел решения этой проблемы и просто создал пару страниц с ответами на вопрос.